# how to use a photodiode to count water drop

Tags: led, sensor, photodiode

So, I am doing a project in which an IR led is emitting light and opposite to that IR led is a photodiode (conventional IR photodiode - which can be found on normal store).

[image]

Between them is a long glass tube with 2 holes on the left and right (to plug the photodiode and led)

Whenever a water drop fall throught the tube , the photodiode signal is changed of course and by detecting that change we can count how many water drops have passed through.

What i want to ask is, How to use a photodiode to do this task- I mean which type of circuit should I use for the photodiode? A transimpedance amplifier (TIA) is suitable or not?

Comment: In situations like this, it is always adviseable to connect everything up and play with the setup. Use an oscilloscope to capture what you see at the photo-diode. Bias the diode different ways.

Comment: I wonder whether using a resonant circuit might work better. A drop of water passing through the dielectric gap of a parallel plate capacitor should change the capacitance dramatically. Never tried it, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a logic level on an analog property with many variables that could span several decades without careful design.

Current \$I_f\$ on emitter, PD gain resistor (0.5mA/mW *R=V) or similar into TIA amp with gain.

The biggest variable is optical scatter around the water drop, thru the tube  and thru the drop. Then alignment of a tiny aperture to restrict the scattering to <<1 deg or just enough to capture the drop and PD detector.

### Design details

- Recessed Emitter and PD detector are both critical to reduce scattering.
- Using a TIA, or a slow 1~10M Rpullup to a buffer or comparator to reverse biased PD to gnd. ( assuming slow drops)
  -start taking measurements for distance then path loss with fixtureat reduced distance
- align for maximum signal variation and use a comparator with xx% hysteresis or a Schmitt trigger gate with 33% Hysteresis if you get enough swing with gain and offset tweaked with pots.
- With testing and trial and error using a black heat shrink tube extended over each 5mm part you can make a 1cm long aperture 5mm diameter that may shrink down to 2mm (est.) which is about the size of the chip inside.
- Layout is critical for stable repeatable logic levels with good margins. i.e. 10 to 90% of Vcc.
- Clean Vcc and twisted pairs with CM choke for noise immunity is important.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your tube, your water-drop source, the LED, the photodiode, and an oscilloscope, in this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frUSSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>